Custom Github Action - Access Github Secrets / environment variable
I'm creating a custom Github Action. I'd like to share this action with others. The issue I'm facing is that within the action code I need to use an API.
I'd like to be able to have my code in the action's repo use the API with an environment variable and/or Github secret. I'm having trouble with this though and am looking for a secure solution.
action.yml (Custom Github Action)
# action.yml needs to be in project root directory
name: 'My Python Action'
description: 'Description of what your action does'

inputs:
  name:
    description: 'Name of the application to be tested'
    required: true

runs:

  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'
  args:
    - --name=${{ inputs.name }}


main.py (simple example)
from os import environ


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--name')
    print(environ['API_KEY'])


name: Test My App with My Python Action

on: [push]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Checkout private action repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository:usr/custom_github_action_repo
          token: ${{ secrets.ACTIONS_PAT }}
          path: ./actions
          ref: main

      - name: Run My Python Action
        uses: ./actions/
        with:
          name: 'example-user-app'

I don't want to expose the API key to the user. I don't even want them to know it's there.
This Github issue I think is similar to the issue I'm facing.
If I put the environment variable in the action.yml users will then have to define the secret in their workflow. I don't want to do this as it will expose the API key.

I would think carefully about this: even if it's possible to securely embed an API key in an action (and I'm not sure that it is), you're liable for trouble if your action ends up being unexpectedly popular and you start hitting limits associated with your API key. I think it would make more sense to have people provide their own API key as input to your action.
